# Alternative to repeatedly printing shapes of the pandas dataframe after every step

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logging

Hello users of pandas,
I often find myself printing the shapes of the dataframes after every step of processing. I do this to monitor how the shape of the data changes and to ensure that it is done correctly.
e.g.

```
print(df.shape)
df=df.dropna()
print(df.shape)
df=df.melt()
print(df.shape)
...
```

I wonder if there is any better/elegant way, preferably a shorthad or an automatic way to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: The answer probably depends on what you're trying to accomplish. What is the reason why you'd like to print the shape after every step? Are you trying to ensure that it does/does not change in a certain way? Are you trying to understand how the data is being modified? Another reason?

Comment: Exactly as you said, I am just "trying to ensure that it (dataframe) does/does not change in a certain way" and  "understand how the data is being modified".   
I hope I am not the only one doing it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I improvised on [Matthew Cox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65083558/3521099), and added an attribute to the pandas dataframe itself. This simplifies things a lot.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# set logger
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# log changes in dataframe
def log_(df, fun, *args, **kwargs):
    logging.info(f'shape changed from {df.shape}', )
    df1 = getattr(df, fun)(*args, **kwargs)
    logging.info(f'shape changed to   {df1.shape}')
    return df1

# custom pandas dataframe
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("log")
class log:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._obj = pandas_obj
    def dropna(self,**kws):
        return log_(self._obj,fun='dropna',**kws)
# demo data    
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ['Alfred', 'Batman', 'Catwoman'],
                   "toy": [np.nan, 'Batmobile', 'Bullwhip'],
                   "born": [pd.NaT, pd.Timestamp("1940-04-25"),
                            pd.NaT]})
# trial
df.log.dropna()
# stderr
INFO:root:shape changed from (3, 3)
INFO:root:shape changed to   (1, 3)
# returns dropna'd dataframe
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you're doing is entirely fine - especially as you are exploring. The code is easy to read and there isn't too much repetitive code. If you really wanted to reduce lines of code, you could utilize a helper function that could wrap whatever you are trying to run. For example:

```
def df_caller(df, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    new_df = getattr(df, fn)(*args, **kwargs)
    print(new_df.shape)
    assert df.shape == new_df.shape
    return new_df

df = df_caller(df, 'dropna')
df = df_caller(df, 'melt')
...
```

However, in my opinion the meta programming in the above solution is a little too magical and harder to read than what you originally posted.

Comment: `df_caller` could take a lambda to avoid passing function names as strings

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to integrate such a function within pandas itself. So that the syntax does not change much. For example, I use `progress_apply` in place of `apply` to get a progress bar. Similarly, there could be an attribute of the dataframe such as `verbose_dropna`/`verbose_melt`, to see how the shapes of the dataframes change.